# Regarding email attachments from gmail app on iphone

Tags: gmail, iphone

I have iphone 5S. I want to know:

1. How to save a doc or pdf attachment from gmail app locally on an iphone?
2. How to view this attachment (from step 1) on iphone?
3. How to send this attachment to someone else using gmail app from iphone?
   The attachment icon only gives the option for photos and google drive link.

I have earlier used gmail app on Android phone and there it was very simple to download or send an attachment but iphone seems to be tricky. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What version of iOS?

Answer (score 1):

For PDF files, you can import into iBooks and simply access it from iBooks. From there you can also send the PDF as an attachment for someone else by clicking on share.

For other files, I think your best bet would be using the Google Drive app or iCloud in order to keep on viewing it on your phone. Another thing you can do is save the files in the notes app and then you can also view it and send it out from there.

For the 5S, I'm sure that you can use iBooks for PDF but I'm not 100% sure on if you can put other file types into notes (although I don't see why not).